# Why am I unable to Send messages to ActiveMQ from WSO2 EI 6.0.0?

Tags: apache, wso2, activemq-classic, esb, wso2-esb

I followed the link [ESB as a JMS Producer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer) to configure the sender and receiver. I have also placed the following jars activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar activemq-client-5.8.0.jar activemq-kahadb-store-5.8.0.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar hawtbuf-1.9.jar Slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar activeio-core-3.1.4.jar into WSO2_EI_HOME/lib

When I configured a proxy with the following code and tried to send the messages to the queue, but the messages aren't delivering.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Sender"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/VALLYSOFTQ?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The same configuration worked earlier for me but I don't know what happened, the messages are not going to the queue now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error fixed after reconfiguring the axis2.xml file re-extracting the EI zip file.

Comment: Didn't you configure axis2 xml before getting the issue ?

Comment: I configured before as well but somehow it didn't work for the reasons unknown.